# Using C# API to connect to Powershell Remoting

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-remoting, winrm

Looking for help with a powershell api connectivity issue.  The following code works for all customers, however, for one of the customers, it is returning an error:

```
var context = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(uri),
                    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell",
                    new PSCredential(username, securePassword))
                              {
                                  SkipCACheck = true,
                                  SkipCNCheck = true
                              };

                using (var pool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(1, counterDefinitions.Count, context))
                {
                    pool.Open();
```

pool.Open() line returns the following exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException'
>   occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll
>
> Additional information: Processing data from remote server
>   xxx.xx.xx.xx failed with the following error message: The request for
>   the Windows Remote Shell with ShellId some-guid-number failed because
>   the shell was not found on the server. Possible causes are: the
>   specified ShellId is incorrect or the shell no longer exists on the
>   server. Provide the correct ShellId or create a new shell and retry
>   the operation. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

If one is to examine the Intellitrace of the exceptions, the one exception thrown a little higher in the stack is as follows:

> "The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the
>   request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is
>   accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the
>   WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or
>   WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following
>   command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service:
>   "winrm quickconfig". " (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) A
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was thrown: "The client
>   cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify
>   that the service on the destination is running and is accepting
>   requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management
>   service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the
>   destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
>   destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm
>   quickconfig". "

Any thoughts as to what could be the problem?  Customer has verified that winrm is running and configured, and that firewall has an open port, etc.

Server is running Windows Server 2012, as a VM on Azure

Answer (score -1):

You may need to configure the TrustedHosts

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555966